# export ROS_HOSTNAME, ROS_MASTER_URI configuration problem

Tags: ros, turtlesim, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I was trying all day to figure out why my cmd won't accept my arrow keys as input for the turtlesim example.
At first I though there was some configuration problem with the shell I use (zsh).
After experimenting a little I noticed that I need to export ROS_HOSTNAME and ROS_MASTER_URI in all 3 tabs I need to run the turtlsime example. So ***in each tab*** I go like:

1. export ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost --- export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311 --- roscore
2. export ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost --- export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311 --- rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node
3. export ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost --- export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311 --- rosrun turtlesim turtle_teleop_key

Only then my cmd will accept my arrow keys as input and I will see the turtle moving. Any idea what I am doing wrong? Is there a way I can avoid this? Like run it once, even if I need to restart my PC?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368292/export-ros_hostname,-ros_master_uri-configuration-problem/) by [mzouros](https://answers.ros.org/users/66264/mzouros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-12-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure why you need to set `ROS_HOSTNAME` to `localhost`, but to avoid having to set these environment variables manually, add them to whichever file your shell loads/parses/`source`s when you start/log into a new shell.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mzouros](https://answers.ros.org/users/66264/mzouros/) on 2020-12-23**:
Tutorial says so.
I just forced edited the rc file as you proposed. Seems to work.
Thanks!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-12-24**:
Which tutorial?

**Comment by [mzouros](https://answers.ros.org/users/66264/mzouros/) on 2020-12-24**:
ROS/NetworkSetup - 2.2. Single Machine Configuration
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-12-24**:
I would not expect that to be necessary for a single machine setup.

I would recommend you try running things without setting those variables, and then see whether things work. If things don't work without those variables, that would point to a potential issue with your network configuration.